# sqlite режим WAL и одновременные транзакции

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

В этой [статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149356/) написано

> Изначально SQlite работал по принципу «многие читают — один пишет».
>   То есть только одно соединение пишет в БД в данный момент времени. Если другие соединения попробуют тоже записать, то словят ошибку SQLITE_BUSY.
>   ...
>   не так давно появился новый вид лога SQlite: Write Ahead Log, WAL.
>   Если включить для БД именно этот режим лога, то несколько подключений смогут одновременно модифицировать БД.

Не могу понять как этим пользоваться. Создаю тестовую бд, у которой journal_mode=WAL и получаю 3 файла, то есть режим активируется.

но простейший тестовый код

```
string conString = @"Data Source=test.db;Version=3;Foreign Keys=true;Connect Timeout=30";

var conn1=new SQLiteConnection(conString);
var conn2=new SQLiteConnection(conString);

conn1.Open();
conn1.BeginTransaction();
conn2.Open();
conn2.BeginTransaction();
```

показывает, что оно зависает на conn2.BeginTransaction(); и потом вылетает, что база данных заблокирована "database is locked"

Как же правильно использовать WAL?